# при попытке заархивировать готовое приложение пишет Module 'flutter_inappwebview' not found

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

сделал все по инструкции для установки `flutter_inappwebview 3.2.0`, но все равно выдает ошибку `Module 'flutter_inappwebview' not found`
не понимаю в чем может быть проблема, нашел одно решение архивировать открыв `Runner.xcworkspace` но в этом случае приложение не появляется в app store connect

[введите сюда описание ссылки](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А откуда вы взяли это. Это генерированный файл в него ничего вставлять не надо. Вы наверное спутали названия файлов.

Comment: Вам необходимо изменить строчку `io.flutter.embedded_views_preview` в `Info.plist` на `YES`. Может быть еще `Podfile` отредактировать. И самое главное, проект должен использовать язык `swift` для сборки.